# Check if Google Earth Engine Python API is initialized

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

In Google Earth Engine Python API, you need to start with an initialization :

```
import ee

ee.Initialize()
```

Is there a way to check if the ee has already been Initialized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

during the init, the API will check and add your credentials and they are accecible so you can just use :

```py
import ee 

if not ee.data._credentials:
    ee.Initialize()
```